# How to deny access to a directory without restricting it local?

Tags: .htaccess

So, I'm currently repairing an old project. Yes, It's old, ugly and unsafe, but i don't get paid to rewrite the entire thing, only to add a new function. Unfortunately, i came across a file called `settings.ini` and saw this:

```
;database
resources.db.adapter = "mysqli"
resources.db.param.host = "xxxxxxxxxx"
resources.db.param.username = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
resources.db.param.password = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
resources.db.param.dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

So, I tried to access them via web browser, and since it's a usual .txt file, if I know the address, I can access it from anywhere I want. I guess i don't have to mention that this is a huge risk for them. Personally, i could say that i don't care or didn't see this, but to be honest, i feel bad doing it. The problem is, I don't have access to the server where this tool is running, so i can't use the firewall to block access from outside.

My first apporach was via `.htaccess`, which contained the following code:

```
<Directory "configs">
Satisfy Any
Order Require,Allow,Deny
Require local
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

The files are in the folder `configs`, this is a simplified file structure:

```
app
|-- folder1
|-- folder2
|-- folder3
|-- configs
|-- .htaccess
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work, I still can access the file via any browser. Is there a chance to achieve this via a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a .htaccess to the folder `configs` with this content:

```
Deny from all
```

If you still need access from a specific IP (e.g. for testing) you can use

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

where `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` is your IP.

You can read more on this on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html

Comment: Doesn't work, just tried it. I can still access the file without any restrictions.

Comment: Seems like your server isn't reading the .htaccess. Put a .htacces with some text garbage in the directory (just some random letters). If you can still access the file, your server doesn't read the .htaccess. See http://askubuntu.com/a/429931 on how to activate them.

Comment: Yeah, it is not reading the .htaccess. Which is weird, since i got one in the root folder with a authentication and it is working fine. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Can you check with the linked askubuntu.com question and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#AllowOverride in my last comment if the .htaccess is enabled correctly? Maybe AllowOverride is set to a wrong value

Comment: Yes, it's probably that. `AllowOverride` is set to `None`. But since that's not my server, I'm not allowed to change it.